# How did sand dunes appear in the midst of a fertile region?

Tags: geomorphology, erosion

I recently visited a place called Talakad/Talakadu about 40 km from Mysore, India. Its an amazing place where a whole city has been covered by sand about 15 m deep. The local myth is that a curse turned the once thriving town to a barren dune. Does anyone have any scientific explanations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the sands at Talakad are the result of a ecological disaster that occurred in the 17th Century. At the time, a dam was constructed north of Talakad on Kaveri River which caused the river to be diverted. This exposed a sand deposit in the river which was subsequently moved to Talakad by monsoonal winds. The following quote is from this source [AB Roy & MS Sethumadhav, 2014](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ashit_Roy/publication/264159940_The_mystic_sand_dune_covered_temples_of_Talakad_Mysore_District_Karnakata_Evidence_of_earthquake_related_destruction/links/53d07fea0cf25dc05cfe4592.pdf):

> It is thought to have originated due to an ‘eco-disaster’ that
>   lashed the region during the 17th century. That was the
>   time when the normal flow of the Kaveri River was
>   impeded because of the construction of a dam on the up-
>   stream side, north of Talakad and subsequent diversion of
>   water in a different direction. As a result, the water level
>   at the point bar on the concave side of the Kaveri meander southwest of Talakad was significantly lowered leading to the buildup of sand at this place. The accumulated
>   sand was then actively reworked and carried by the
>   northeasterly monsoon winds, which were subsequently
>   deposited around Talakad engulfing the temples and other
>   settlements in the region. The yellow coloured, uniformly fine-grained and homogeneous nature of the sand
>   without any clay material in it provides further proof that
>   the air-borne sand deposited as dunes